# parse push notification not receiving

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to get push notification from parse on android.

Tried doing the push notification tutorial on parse.com and searching online for other ppls solution but to no avail.

Can someone please help.

this is the log i get on android studio.

```
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
V/com.parse.ParseHttpClient: Using net.java.URLConnection library for networking communication.
V/com.parse.ManifestInfo: Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
V/com.parse.ManifestInfo: Using none for push.
V/com.parse.CachedCurrentInstallationController: Successfully deserialized Installation object
V/com.parse.ParsePushChannelsController: Tried to subscribe or unsubscribe from a channel, but push is not enabled correctly. Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to use GCM for push: make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
D/Atlas: Validating map...
Successfully subscribed to Parse!
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.321ms
```

I also done the required permissions already

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".CustomPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="{package name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <permission android:name="{package name}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="{package name}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!--
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".CustomPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>-->
</application>
```

Here is my code for parse configuration
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

```
    //Security of data
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // If you would like objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("device_id", mPhoneNumber);
    installation.saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Non-emergencyambulance", "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
        }
    });
```

And here is my custom push receiver
public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
{

```
@Override
protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Notification notification = super.getNotification(context, intent);
    // TODO Update this notification here
    return notification;
}

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO For app specific implementation comment the following line calling super version of this method
    // super.onPushOpen(context, intent);

    //TODO Add App Specific implementation below
    Intent lastIntent = new Intent(context,MainPageActivity.class);
    lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(lastIntent);
}
```

}